# If statement in

Tags: mysql

I am aggregating sql from a select query into a json array like this:

```
CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('value', measured_at, 'day', datediff(measurements.measured_at, athletes.tracking_started_at))), ']') as `values`
```

At times the json object returns a negative value from the `datediff`. What I'd like to do is not return a json object at all in that case.

eg. what I get now:

```
[{ "value": 23, "day": 12 }, { "value": 23, "day": -25 }, { "value": 23, "day": 40 }]
```

what I'd like to get:

```
[{ "value": 23, "day": 12 }, { "value": 23, "day": 40 }]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression inside `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  CASE 
    WHEN datediff(measurements.measured_at, athletes.tracking_started_at) >= 0 
      THEN JSON_OBJECT('value', measured_at, 'day', datediff(measurements.measured_at, athletes.tracking_started_at))
  END
)
```